# Xmlstarlet executable file or any alternatives

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

Xmlstarlet is perfectly fits my needs, but faced issue, that it has no executable file (something like .jar file and etc).

I am trying to use it via a shell script, but server has no xmlstarlet installed by default there (and it's not possible to install it).

Is there any way to put any executable file for Xmlstarlet in my repository? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile the source.

```
git clone git://xmlstar.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/xmlstar/xmlstar
cd xmlstar
./autogen.sh --with-libxml-prefix=/usr --with-libxslt-prefix=/usr
./configure
make
ls -1
./xmlstarlet help
```

No need root user.

See: https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/source.php

Comment: just little addition, that its required to use autoreconf -sif, instead of autogen.sh. throws the error like "autogen.sh is obsolete".

so it needs to be installed via brew install automake

Thats helped me! Thanks!

Comment: maybe you know how to make it executable on linux? looks like any complited sources on mac cannot be executable on linux. maybe its possible to download any already compiled files?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Cross compilations?

Comment: I need to edit xml files when e2e tests running. 
So, I can't just install xmlstarlet on server, that's why I need executable file, which works on linux. I compiled file for macos, so it works perfectly locally. But when pipelines running, I have an error that says "not executable binary file". I find out that its depends on which platform the source code was compiled.

Comment: You can compile on the server, then modify the PATH variable to search your executable in the built directory you compiled

Comment: well, idk know why, but xmlstarlet looks broken to compile on linux (ubuntu).
its not that easy as on mac.

Comment: Quite a vague assertion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969657/xmlstarlet-compile-sources-for-executable-binary-file

did another topic. i think this one is kind of complete